# NFL Pro Bowl 2019

Tags: american-football, nfl

Was there a coin toss to decide who gets ball first ? If so, what was the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that either the AFC won the toss to begin the game, or that the NFC won and deferred.  The following information indicates there was a coin toss.

Looking at [this statistic PDF document of the Pro Bowl held in 2018](http://www.nflgsis.com/2017/post/05/57501/gamebook.pdf) it can be seen that the NFC won it last year.  (it's at the top of page 9 in this document)  This document is linked on the Wikipedia page for last year's Pro Bowl game.  This year's Pro Bowl game Wikipedia page does not have a link yet for such a document, and this site is password-protected.

Since there is no news that the rules have changed for the Pro Bowl to this effect (i.e. eliminating a coin toss), it can be assumed that a coin toss would have determined the AFC receiving the ball first.  I believe it is safe to say that teams do not choose to defer in the Pro Bowl.  I would say that the AFC won it and chose to receive.